# How can I create mask images in Python 3 using features.rasterize?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Currently, I use the following piece of code to create mask images (`classes = ['tree', 'car', 'bicycle']`, `polygons` is the list of the geometry objects where each geometry object has `coordinates` field that defines the polygon on the image that is a bounding box for the class object):

```
def create_mask(self, mask_size, classes, polygons):
    # type (Tuple[int, int], List[str], List[geometry]) -> Image
    # Create a new palette image, the default color of Image.new() is black
    # https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes
    img = Image.new('P', mask_size)
    img.putpalette(self.palette) # palette = [0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, ...]
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    for i, class_ in enumerate(classes):
        color_index = self.class_to_color_index[class_]
        draw.polygon(xy=polygons[i].exterior.coords, fill=color_index)
    del draw
    return img
```

Is there any way to rewrite this piece of code with using [`features.rasterize`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.rasterize)?